# Convert facebook date time to C# date time

Tags: c#, facebook, datetime, epoch

Hi i have notice  there two date times facebook gives, one is a date time from Unix Epoch and other is [RFC 3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339) Datetime (if i am not wrong). I wanted to know what is the best way to convert between each other. I have tried DateTime.TryParse() method but some times it dosent return the correct parsed date. Like it gives `21-Dec-2010 7:21:56 AM` for `2010-12-21T01:51:56+0000`. But it seems it doesn't parse time correctly. So plese tell how to change between **epoch** times and above datetime in C# datetime.

Comment: Please don't ask two unrelated questions at once.

Comment: oh ok i have deleted that portion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DateTime.Parse` is converting a UTC date to your local timezone.
To retrieve the original UTC date, call `ToUniversalTime()`.

Comment: Thanx i had a feeling like it was doing so, because i am from India and its in 5.5 timezone from UTC. How can i make sure the client who is in another timezone gets the right time because the time conversion is done from my servers timezone. And what about Epoch

Comment: Use the [`TimeZoneInfo` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.aspx).

Comment: DateTime.Parse doesn't seem to do the trick with me here.
For the created_date 1289838511, I get a FormatException with the message "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.". Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Mmm. It seems that the date I get is very different from what you have. Why? The value I posted in the previous message is the value of the field created_time after executing a query to get the user wall posts (using FQL).

Comment: To parse a UNIX timestamp, you can call `new DateTime(1970,1,1).AddSeconds(long.Parse(x))`

Comment: @SLaks if we Serialize a datetime through JavascriptSerializer class, what does it return me a Unix time or a windows time.. I have seen it is giving tiks but if i try to parse same tiks as datetime object, it fails in giving correct date.

Comment: @Slaks - thanks! You solved the problem I came here looking to solve.